# $G$ group of order $n$. Can $[\operatorname{Sym}(G):\operatorname{Aut}(G)]$ and $|\operatorname{Out}(G)|$ be expressed in terms of $n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, with $|G|=n$.

$\mbox{¿}$Are there explicit expressions, in terms of $n$, for the two indexes:

- $k:=[\operatorname{Sym}(G):\operatorname{Aut}(G)]=k(n)$
- $l:=[\operatorname{Aut}(G):\operatorname{Inn}(G)]$ $(=|\operatorname{Out}(G)|)=l(n)$

Why am I asking this: $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$, so that $n!=|\operatorname{Sym}(G)|=k|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|=kl|\operatorname{Inn}(G)|=kln/|Z(G)|$, *i.e.* $(n-1)!=kl/|Z(G)|$. In particular, if $G$ is centerless we get:

$$(n-1)!=kl \tag 1$$

We know that if $n=p^N$, $p$ prime, then $G$ can't be centerless (application of the Class Equation). So, I expect that if $n=p^N$, $p$ prime, $(1)$ can't hold. Unless I'm mistaken in the logic, I was hoping to show it explicitely once I had $k(n)$ and $l(n)$ in hands.

Comment: The answer is trivially no, since different groups with equal $n$ can have different $k,l$. For instance, consider $\mathbb Z/4$ and $\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/2$. They both have $n=4$, the former has $k=12,l=2$ and the latter has $k=4,l=6$. So $k,l$ can't be functions of just $n$.

Comment: Yes, I see: the order only can' t tell the whole story. So let me ask this, then: do $n$, $k$ and $l$ characterize completely $G$ (up to isomorphisms)?

Comment: The dihedral and dicyclic groups of order $12$ both have center of order $2$ and automorphism group of order $12$.

Comment: So no, they do not completely characterize $G$. My original aim, anyway, was more limited: prove that $(1)$ can't hold for finite $p$-groups.

Comment: It's an immediate verification that (1) is equivalent to $G$ having trivial center.

Comment: @YCor. That's the point: I want to prove that $(1)$ can't hold if $G$ has order $p^N$, $p$ prime, to conclude that such $G$ can't be centreless. Is my logic wrong?